# true of using parent::__construct() in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(form);
}
```

I have searched for this question and found one or two but no one answered 
    it clearly please explain we are calling the parent __constructor of the extended class  as tutorials said , some website says this step necessary because it is required to override the parent class http://tutorialsplane.com/codeigniter-controller-constructor, and when i looked in the ***base library***
          I have found this description  for the default controller constructor

> > **Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
> >                bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
> >               so that CI can run as one big super object.**

and finally some one says that is requrid to load controller https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-php-framework
now i am totally confused  does it required for using controller   methods so why we have inhirited the controller class   and what is the benefit of  overriding parent constructor
 please help................................

Comment: _constructor source code   http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/source-class-CI_Controller.html#34-54

Answer (score 0):

There's no clear benefit of overriding the constructor.

However, **if** you want to override it for some reason (which in this case you do to load a helper), you have to call the parent constructor in order to keep its functionality in tact.

If you don't need any custom logic in a constructor, you're not at all required to declare a `__construct()` method yourself and in that case you'll just inherit the parent one.

Comment: this is why i am strangling   I can load the helper through any place in the child class without calling the parent constructor i just wan't to know what the parent constructor add to my child class ....thank you